# Computing AUC or, generally, doing prediction with the Zelig package in R?

Tags: r, logistic, data-mining, roc, auc

I'm using the model ReLogit from the package Zelig in R. ReLogit is a logistic regression for rare events data.
After having estimated the model on the training set, I want to calculate the AUC (Area under the ROC Curve) of this model in the test set. 
How can I do this with this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is using the `pROC` package. 
In `Zelig` I think you can use `rocplot` or something to extract the statistic.

Let's say we estimate `m1`, then one way to calculate the AUC is:

```
library(pROC)
library(Zelig)

data(mid) # Data on Militarized Interstate Disputes from King & Zeng (2001)
m1<-relogit(conflict~.,mid)
auc(as.numeric(m1$model[1]>0),as.vector(fitted(m1)))

Area under the curve: 0.9235
```

And now we're at it, it's also easy to plot the ROC:

```
plot(roc(as.numeric(m1$model[1]>0),as.vector(fitted(m1))))
```

[image]

Comment: The curve doesn't help and the area is just the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U-statistic (concordance probability).  In R you can compute that with one line.  See for example the `Hmisc` package's `somers2` function.